# How to calculate the MD5 hash of a large file in C?

Tags: c, hash, md5

I am writing in C using OpenSSL library.

How can I calculate hash of a large file using md5?

As I know, I need to load a whole file to RAM as char array and then call the hash function. But what if the file is about 4Gb long? Sounds like a bad idea.

**SOLVED**: Thanks to [askovpen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1347147/askovpen), I found my bug. I've used

```
while ((bytes = fread (data, 1, 1024, inFile)) != 0)
    MD5_Update (&mdContext, data, 1024);
```

not

```
while ((bytes = fread (data, 1, 1024, inFile)) != 0)
    MD5_Update (&mdContext, data, bytes);
```

Comment: I'm curious to know the need for it? It certainly could be a bad idea if it's not thread safe, since it could block the program for an extended period and P.O. the user

Comment: Encrypting a file is not the same as hashing it with a hash function like MD5. Do you really mean hash, or do you want to encrypt the file?

Comment: MD5 is stream-based.  You don't need to load the entire 4GB into memory at once - you read it in chunks.

Comment: Sorry, of course I mean hashing file, not encrypting.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

example

`gcc -g -Wall -o file file.c -lssl -lcrypto`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/md5.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char c[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    char *filename="file.c";
    int i;
    FILE *inFile = fopen (filename, "rb");
    MD5_CTX mdContext;
    int bytes;
    unsigned char data[1024];

    if (inFile == NULL) {
        printf ("%s can't be opened.\n", filename);
        return 0;
    }

    MD5_Init (&mdContext);
    while ((bytes = fread (data, 1, 1024, inFile)) != 0)
        MD5_Update (&mdContext, data, bytes);
    MD5_Final (c,&mdContext);
    for(i = 0; i < MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) printf("%02x", c[i]);
    printf (" %s\n", filename);
    fclose (inFile);
    return 0;
}
```

result:

```
$ md5sum file.c
25a904b0e512ee546b3f47574703d9fc  file.c
$ ./file
25a904b0e512ee546b3f47574703d9fc file.c
```

Comment: may 
    unsigned char data[1024];
    while ((bytes = fread (data, 1, 1024, inFile)) != 0)
be 
    unsigned char data[4096];
    while ((bytes = fread (data, 1, 4096, inFile)) != 0)
?

Answer (score 6):

First, MD5 is a hashing algorithm. It doesn't encrypt anything.

Anyway, you can read the file in chunks of whatever size you like. Call [MD5_Init](http://linux.die.net/man/3/md5_update) once, then call [MD5_Update](http://linux.die.net/man/3/md5_update) with each chunk of data you read from the file. When you're done, call [MD5_Final](http://linux.die.net/man/3/md5_update) to get the result.

Comment: I've tried that. I've splitted file to 16-byte blocks and passed them to MD5_Update, but the hash was wrong.

Comment: So fix the bug in your code that caused the hash to be wrong. (Also, 16 byte blocks will be slow. You'd do a lot better using 64KB blocks at lease.)

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to load the entire file in memory at once.  You can use the functions  [MD5_Init(), MD5_Update() and MD5_Final()](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/md5.html) to process it in chunks to produce the hash.  If you are worried about making it an "atomic" operation, it may be necessary to lock the file to prevent someone else changing it during the operation.

Answer (score 1):

The top answer is correct, but didn't mention something: The value of the hash will be different for each buffer size used. The value will be consistent across hashes, so the same buffer size will produce the same hash everytime, however if this hash will be compared against a hash of the same data at a later time, the same buffer size must be used for each call.

In addition, if you want to make sure your digest code functions correctly, and go online to compare your hash with the online hashing websites, it appears they use a buffer length of 1. This also brings an interesting thought: It is perfectly acceptable to use a buffer length of 1 to hash a large file, it will just take longer (*duh*).

So my rule of thumb is if it's only for internal use, then I can set the buffer length accordingly for a large file, but if it has to play nice with other systems, then set the buffer length to 1 and deal with the time consequence.

```
int hashTargetFile(FILE* fp, unsigned char** md_value, int *md_len) {

    #define FILE_BUFFER_LENGTH 1

    EVP_MD_CTX *mdctx;
    const EVP_MD *md;
    int diglen; //digest length
    int arrlen = sizeof(char)*EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE + 1;
    int arrlen2 = sizeof(char)*FILE_BUFFER_LENGTH + 1;
    unsigned char *digest_value = (char*)malloc(arrlen);
    char *data = (char*)malloc(arrlen2);
    size_t bytes; //# of bytes read from file

    mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_new();
    md = EVP_sha512();

    if (!mdctx) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while creating digest context.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if (!EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx, md, NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while initializing digest context.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    while (bytes = fread(data, 1, FILE_BUFFER_LENGTH, fp) != 0) {
        if (!EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, data, bytes)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error while digesting file.\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    if (!EVP_DigestFinal_ex(mdctx, digest_value, &diglen)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while finalizing digest.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    *md_value = digest_value;
    *md_len = diglen;

    EVP_MD_CTX_free(mdctx);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I ran askovpen's code using various file buffer sizes (40k, 4k, 23, and 1) and got the same hash value every time. Anyone know more about this?

Comment: For anyone coming long later - that's because the fread will only read to the end of the file and the value of bytes is the number of bytes read. So if you have a FILE_BUFFER_LENGTH of 512 and the file is 513 bytes long on the first iteration bytes = 512 and on the second iteration bytes = 1

It doesn't matter what the buffer size is as long as it's used consistently.

Comment: If you are reading an arbitrary length of the file (like say you want to get a hash of the first N bytes (useful if you are checking to see if file 1 is a subset of the data of file 2) you need to either use a buffer size of 1 *or* use 2 while loops. The first reads the data in buffer length chunks (while hit bytes_read+buffer_length < size) and then the second reads in data in 1 byte increments while bytes_read < size.