# How to calculate the hash of a file in C or C++?

Tags: c++, c

I am working on calculating Deduplication percentage. Given two files as input and using hash.
For that first I have to calculate the hash of the file preferably in C/C++. If anyone has the code can you please post it here. It would be very helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C++, How to get MD5 hash of a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220046/in-c-how-to-get-md5-hash-of-a-file)

Comment: Another possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324611/how-to-calculate-the-md5-hash-of-a-large-file-in-c

Comment: What type of hash? One of the standard hashes (like MD5 or SHA1), or something of your own design?

Comment: And please stick with one language, the solution(s) might be considerably different depending on language.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Md5 in c

Comment: @roelofs  openssl/md5.h:No such file or directory  this is the error,with the code you mentioned.

Comment: Have you got the openssl-dev package installed? (assuming you're working in a linux environment)

Answer (score 2):

[Boost hash](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/hash.html) You could use this, but any other librairy would work. Looks like you did poor research.