# How can go MD5 be so fast? crypto/md5

Tags: c, bash, unix, go, md5

I need to compute the hash (md5 is ok) for a large number of files. So, in Go I have this code:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "path/filepath"

    "crypto/md5"
    "encoding/hex"
)

func strSliceRemove(slice []string, str string) []string {
    var tempSlice []string;

    for _, item := range slice {
        if item != str {
            tempSlice = append(tempSlice, item)
        }
    }

    return tempSlice
}

func fileMD5(path string) (string, error) {
    var returnMD5String string
    file, err := os.Open(path)

    if err != nil {
        return returnMD5String, err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    hash := md5.New()

    if _, err := io.Copy(hash, file); err != nil {
        return returnMD5String, err
    }

    hashInBytes := hash.Sum(nil)[:16]
    returnMD5String = hex.EncodeToString(hashInBytes)

    return returnMD5String, nil
}

func main() {
    var doRead func(string)

    doRead = func(sd string) {
        filepath.Walk(sd, func(path string, f os.FileInfo, err error) error {
            resolvedPath, resolvedPathErr := filepath.EvalSymlinks(path)
            if resolvedPathErr != nil {
                return nil
            }

            if f.Mode()&os.ModeSymlink == os.ModeSymlink {
                doRead(resolvedPath)
            } else {
                if !f.IsDir() {
                    md5, _ := fileMD5(path)
                    fmt.Printf("%s\n", md5)
                }
            }

            return nil
        })
    }

    doRead("/tmp/electron")
    return
}
```

It hashes correctly 1400 files in almost one second. If I use my OSX md5 command line utility, it takes more than 10 times the time. It is 10 times slower:

```
for FILE in `find /tmp/electron`; do
    if [ ! -d "$FILE" ]; then
        md5 $FILE;
    fi;
done;
```

I tried a basic c program that does the same (based on this answer [How to calculate the MD5 hash of a large file in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324611/how-to-calculate-the-md5-hash-of-a-large-file-in-c)) and still the time seems more or less 10 seconds.

What kind of strategy / library does crypto/md5 use?

Comment: Don't you think the factor 10 can reasonably be explained by the overhead incurred by the shell version? Eg, it has to load and initialize the md5 and test ( [ ) executables at least 1400 times whereas the go program is loaded once. The source for crypto/md5 is [here](https://golang.org/src/crypto/md5/md5.go)

Comment: What time is spent in claculating MD5 and what time is spent in traversing directories?

Comment: Replace `md5` in your shell script with `echo` and measure time.

Comment: Traversing: 0.127s
Calculating the md5: 11.420s

Comment: Use: `find /tmp/electron -type f -exec md5 {} +` and see how fast that is.

Comment: I did a brief not overly scientific experiment, an md5 utility in go that calculates the md5 from its stdin and ran it like this `time dd if=/dev/zero bs=10240 count=200000 | ./md5`. Execution time is around 6 seconds on my test vm, almost identical to `time dd if=/dev/zero bs=10240 count=200000 | md5sum`, the OS std C implementation of md5. So, it's not the md5 algorithm that makes the difference.

Comment: On a Mac using Common Crypto I get slightly over 400MB/s. That does not include file access, read and write time. fvu got 200000 * 10240 / 6 ~= 341 MB/s which is close given possibly different Macs.